# Retarget printf to a serial port

Tags: c, embedded, printf, stdout, stm32

I want use the function `printf` to print character on the serial port. I have read these 2 posts [1](http://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/10/use-printf-output-stream-stm32f4/) and [2](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/arm/Retargetting_a_C_library_function/), But I'am not sure to understand the manip:

in the [1st link](http://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/10/use-printf-output-stream-stm32f4/) it's said:

To enable printf functionality, first you need to create a new `__FILE` struct. This struct is then called with FILE struct.

Why I have to create `__FILE` struct I didn't realy undrestand this sentence.

In the [2nd link](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/arm/Retargetting_a_C_library_function/) it's said

To complete the separation from the standard I/O library we also have had to redefine `__stdout` and `__stdin`. These can be found inside the retarget.c file below the declaration of the `__FILE` structure.

If I redefine these 2 variables isn't that a compilation error I mean a redefinition.

Comment: That sure seems like the hard way to do it.  Do you have `dup2()`?  Does your platform have a "normal" `stdout` file descriptor value, such as Linux using file descriptor `1` for `stdout`?  If so, just do something like `int fd = open( "/path/to/port"...); dup2( fd, STDOUT_FILENO);`.  You might want to disable `stdout` buffering.

Comment: Maybe freopen could be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Andrew Henle as i undrestand `printf` will use `fputc` to display the caracter on the scrreen so somewhere in `printf` function there is a call to `fputc(stdout, car)` so at this point if we have duplicated stdout fd the `car` will also be printd in the new fd (created by dup) but what happens then ?

Comment: @ JohnTortugo According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdo) , it could be quite easy using `freopen ("/dev/tty", "a", stdout)` but actually am not using linux, anyway it may give some inspiration i will investigate more

Comment: Seems like hard work to change the stdout handling underneath printf. Do you want to do it this way because you don't want to change existing printf() statemennts? If you can change those printf(), why not simply define serprintf() which uses sprintf() (or vsprintf()) to print to a string and then it outputs the string to the serialport?

Comment: @barny yes this is the main reason, the above links describe the solution but i actually don't undrestand how they are working, of course i can change the printf with serprintf but it's question of curiosity

Comment: @Mouin The links you provided are about trying to "separat[e] from the standard I/O library" in a very platform-specific way. As far as I can tell from  what you've provided, your platform doesn't fully implement all C standard library functions, nor is it POSIX-compliant.  So things like `dup2()` don't appear to be available. Is this what you're limited to:  http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_stdio_h.htm  If so, you probably will have to write something like the code you provided the links to. Be aware, though, that such hacks will be platform-specific and easily broken.

Comment: Sometimes embedded compilers already direct stdout to the serial port, because otherwise printf would obviously be completely useless. So how do to this depends a lot on which compiler that is used.

Comment: @AndrewHenle STM32 is an ARM microcontroller. This is likely a freestanding implementation, in which case desktop stuff like POSIX doesn't make any sense. Freestanding implementations don't have to provide stdio.h.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retarget printf() on an STM32F10x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815221/how-to-retarget-printf-on-an-stm32f10x)

Answer (score 1):

This may possibly a duplication of [How to make printf work on STM32F103?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664071/how-to-make-printf-work-on-stm32f103/)

I will put my answer, which I posted in the above thread, here too, anyway.

Writing an own `printf` implementation is an option, and probably the most recommended option according to me. Get some inspiration from the standard library implementation and write your own version, only to cater your requirements. In general, what you have to do is, first retarget a `putc` function to send char s through your serial interface. Then override the `printf` method by using the `putc` custom implementation. Perhaps, a very simple approach is sending the string character-wise by recursive calls for `putc` function.

Last but not least, you can find some lightweight `printf` implementations. The code size and the set of features offered by these lightweight implementations lie in between the custom written `printf` function and the stock standard `prinf` function (aka the beast). I have recently tried this and very pleased with its performance on an ARM core in terms of memory footprint and the number of execution cycles required. http://www.sparetimelabs.com/tinyprintf/tinyprintf.php

-PS

Copied from my own writings sometime back - http://mycola.info/2015/02/09/lightweight-printfscanf-for-embedded-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code in your code

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)
#else
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fputc(int ch, FILE * f)
#endif

PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE {
    HAL_UART_Transmit( & huart2, (uint8_t * ) & ch, 1, 0xFFFF);
    return ch;
}
```

Only thing to edit is this line, set it as per your device serial port driver

`HAL_UART_Transmit( & huart2, (uint8_t * ) & ch, 1, 0xFFFF);`